# Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxxx/_packaging/yyyyy/nuget/v3/index.json

Tags: azure, nuget, devops, nuget-package-restore

I an getting this error :Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxxx/_packaging/xxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json.
      Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).)

i am trying to restore package from an azure artifact of other organisation.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdMCX.png)

error log:
  38 package(s) to packages.config projects

### [error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in packages.config projects

```
Unable to find version '1.0.976930' of package 'xxxx.Security.Eso.Web.DevSignOn'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'xxxx.Security.Eso.Web.DevSignOn.1.0.976930' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
  https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxx/_packaging/yyyy/nuget/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxx/_packaging/yyyy/nuget/v3/index.json.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).)
```

### [error]Packages failed to restore

i tried these solutions but no luck:
1. https://mallibone.com/post/private-nuget-feed-azure-devops
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/packages/nuget-restore?view=azure-devops

Comment: What ended up being your solution?

Answer (score 8):

Re-entering account credentials in VS worked for me.

Comment: For anybody searching: File -> Account Settings -> Click on re-enter credentials (next to the yellow warning sign).

But in my case it did not solve the problem, not found a solution yet.

Comment: Edit: In my case the problem appeared after running `dotnet new console -o EFGetStarted`.  When I manually open the created solution, the error does not appear so that was my 'solution' to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me, [link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6135#issuecomment-397847293). From github user [@danilobreda](https://github.com/danilobreda)

Below is the answer from the link above:

---

What worked for me... using the PAT token.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:latest AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
COPY NuGet.Config ./
RUN dir
RUN dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.Config -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503 --verbosity diag
RUN dotnet publish --output /output --configuration Release

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /output /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerProject.dll"]
```

and my NuGet.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="BredasVSTS" value="https://xxxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/BredasVSTS/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <BredasVSTS>
      <add key="Username" value="emailhere" />      
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="PAT here" />
    </BredasVSTS>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

The Username parameter need to be passed but you can set a random username/phrase there... since PAT does not have username parameter.
Make sure that the nuget package have permissions (read and write) of PAT owner.

Comment: "Make sure that the nuget package have permissions (read and write) of PAT owner" What for write premission?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on this last comment?

Comment: Here's a link with steps to create a PAT (Personal Access Token) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows

Answer (score 0):

Repair Visual Studio installation worked for me.